# Spring boot token authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I trying to make login to Spring Boot application for another application  and generate token using Spring Security. What I try to achieve:

1. Username and password are send to REST controller.
2. If username and password is ok I want to generate token with 30 minutes expire time and send it back to user.
3. Token is used to verify user in `@PreAuthorized` methods.

Is the way to achive this in Spring Security or should I make it manually? I don't know how to save a token like Spring session using Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

I use spring-boot-starter-parent version **1.5.7.RELEASE**.

My approach is not a complete solution but it might help you.

You will be able to send user/password and get a SESSION cookie which then can be used further on.

Caveat:

- You still need to set the expiration time of the cookie/token.
- You need to automate the process of logging in - directly send the user credentials (This approach serves a login.html...).

---

Provided you already have **spring boot security** enabled in your pom.

Also add the following to enable **session management** and **redis as HTTP session store** (in your pom):

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

Add a class that `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. You might already have that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // enable method-level authorization (@PreAuthorize("expression"))
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
     @Autowired
     public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
     }

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic().disable();
  http
          .csrf().disable()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .usernameParameter("j_username")
          .passwordParameter("j_password")
          .loginPage("/login.html")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/#")
          .failureUrl("/loginNotSuccessfull.html")
          .permitAll();
}
```

Also I have a **redis** server as HTTP session store (I just started a docker container using the `redis:4-alpine` image and `--protected-mode no` and `--net=host`.) with the following properties in **application.properties**:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

To make it work, I also included a **HTTPSessionConfig** class to enable [redis HTTP sessions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html#boot-redis-configuration):

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

}
```

Spring boot handles all the necessary stuff - storing the user in redis, checking the SESSION etc.

---

I hope this is all working as expected.

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

**Update:**

[This link shows](https://drissamri.be/blog/2015/05/21/spring-security-and-spring-session/), how to use an embedded redis server.