# How do I manage login credentials with Spring MVC running on multiple instances

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting ready to develop an AWS Spring MVC Web Application that uses Spring login security.  I have used it in the past but only with a single instance.  I am getting ready to develop a new application that uses AWS Elastic Load Balancing and instance scaling.  How does Spring handle login credentials when running on multiple instances?  In other words, I log into my web application running on instance-1 and the next session I am making a request on instance-2.  How do I handle user credentials between each instance?  I am sure this is a common design scenario for Spring MVC Security.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471516/spring-boot-token-authentication/46905527#46905527). It refers to redis as HTTP session store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you could explore:

- Configure sticky sessions (something that AWS ELB supports) so that all requests for a given session will go to the same instance.
- Store session information outside your application, for example in a Redis cache. One clear benefit of this approach is that your application will be better resilient to instance failures, because with sticky sessions all customers tied to a failed instance would have to re-login.

Comment: Hello Ketan, I agree with your comments on Sticky sessions.  I thought of this but rejected for similar reasons you highlighted.  Can you give me some hints on what credentials I need to save and how do I pass them from my browser to the new instance?  I have not found anything on the web that discusses this web pattern.

Comment: Load balancer's sticky session worked for our IBM Websphere environment too.

Comment: @skmansfield Are you asking about the 2nd approach? There are various resources on it online. Start with [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=spring+security+redis&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=UjbwWZXoDeH98we7qpOgBQ)

Comment: Ashish, sticky sessions will work, however, if an instance fails in between sessions the user will have to re-login.  I was interested in the 2nd method -- Caching user Spring credentials.  The first time someone logs into a Spring MVC session, a set of credentials are created and saved in that instance.  The next session may get directed to another instance by the AWS Elastic Load Balancer.  The new instance has no knowledge of these credentials.  Ketan's reference is a good start for the second method.  I have what I need...